# Python 2.7: How to extract filename from exception object

Tags: python, exception, object, python-2.7, filenames

Referring to the [traceback documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html), it says

> Note that the filename is available as the filename attribute of the exception
>   object.

But when I try to call the error object using the code:

```
 errorIndex = fileList.index(os.error.filename)
```

it gives me the error:

```
ValueError: <member 'filename' of 'exceptions.EnvironmentError' objects> is not in list
```

I am using python 2.7. Can anyone explain this error and what I am doing wrong?

Edit (Full Code):

```
def readFile(path, im_format, number_of_loops): 
fileList = sorted(os.listdir(path))
try:
    for file in fileList: #sorted function ensures files are read in ascending order
        if file.endswith(im_format):
            image_array = mahotas.imread(file)
            T = mahotas.thresholding.otsu(image_array)
            image = image_array>T
            image = img_as_ubyte(image)
            mahotas.imsave('C:/users/imgs/new/im_%00005d.tiff'%counter, image.astype(np.uint8))
except :
    errorIndex = fileList.index(os.error.filename)
    image_array1 = mahotas.imread(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'imgs',fileList[errorIndex-1]))
    T = mahotas.thresholding.otsu(image_array1)

    image1 = image_array1>T


    image_array2 = mahotas.imread(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'imgs',fileList[errorIndex+1]))
    T = mahotas.thresholding.otsu(image_array2)

    image2 = image_array2>T


    average = [(x+y)/2 for x,y in zip(image1,image2)]
    mahotas.imsave('C:/users/average.tiff'%counter, average.astype(np.uint8))
    fileList[errorIndex] = ('C:/users/imgs/average.tiff'%counter)
```

Comment: That looks like you're trying to access it on the error class, no on an actual error.  Can you post the rest of the code where you're using this?

Comment: @BrenBarn I added all relevant code. I hope this helps.

Comment: You need to catch a specific exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename attribute will be on a specific instance of an exception.  You need something like:

```
except os.error as e:
    errorIndex = fileList.index(e.filename)
```

As currently written your code makes me nervous.  You seem to have a lot of code inside an `except` block.  Generally all you want to do in an `except` block is the minimum necessary to handle the specific error you're trying to handle.  By the same token, your `try` block is large, meaning that many different errors could occur in it.  You should generally make the `try` block as small as possible, so that you only attempt to handle a carefully limited set of possible errors.

If you want to catch an IOError, you need to write that, using `except IOError as e`.  You can use `except (IOError, OSError) as e` to catch either kind of error.

Comment: Thanks for your input. When I do this, it seems to ignore the `except` block completely, and I simply get an IOerror as if it weren't there: `IOError: cannot identify image file`. The error is coming from the for loop the first time the file is supposed to be read. Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: @nichosukiennik: See my edited answer.  Your question didn't say anything about IOError.  If you want to catch IOError, you need to do `except IOError`.

Comment: I see what's wrong here. I replaced `except os.error as e:` with `except IOError as e:`. Now I get a new error: `ValueError: None is not in list`.

Comment: @nichosukiennik: You're getting beyond the issue that your question was originally about.  You need to try to debug your code to figure out why it's raising that error.  It may not be for the reason you think it is.  I would suggest that you make your `try` block smaller, only including the code whose error you actually want to catch.

Comment: You're right. Thank you very much for your help. You did answer my original question.

Comment: @nichosukiennik: No problem.  If you run into a wall debugging you can always ask a separate question about that other problem.